# How to play youtube videos automatically in Android HTML5Webview above Android 2.3

Tags: android

Auto Play of Youtube video works well below Android 2.3 but in above versions requires touch gesture to play the video.

I am using the (javascript + Iframe) Api of Youtube to play the video.

Hardware Acceleration is already enabled.

Answer (score 1):

set this in meanifeast.xml

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

**hardwareAccelerated** works in above 3.0. so you can play video in WebView.

refer this [android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable hardware acceleration on the web view.